# Is it true that if $x^2$ > $y^2$, then $x<y^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I need to write a proof, and my method of proof requires the following:

> If $x^2 > y^2$, then $x < y^2$.

But I can't find it as a theorem or postulate or anything anywhere. If it helps, both x and y would be positive numbers. I was wondering if this is true, or if it's just my wishful thinking.

Comment: That's simply not true. Let x=10, y=1. Your statement doesn't hold in general.

Comment: *Real* positive numbers?

Comment: Thank you @Dargscisyhp!

and yes @Bernard

Comment: What are you actually trying to prove? If this statement is absolutely required for your theorem to be true, then your theorem is necessarily false. My guess is therefore that there's another way to complete your proof.

Comment: $x^{2} > y^{2} \implies \left(~\left\vert\, x\,\right\vert < - \left\vert\, y\,\right\vert \ \mbox{or}\ \left\vert\, x\,\right\vert > \left\vert\, y\,\right\vert~\right)$.

Comment: @MichaelLee that i is less than or equal to the effective annual rate which is less than or equal to e^i - 1

It was just an idea I had (which was obviously wrong)

Comment: Well, no, your conjecture isn't necessarily wrong at all. You're just going about it the wrong way. You're trying to show that $i \leq \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n-1 \leq e^i-1$ for all $n \geq 1$?

Comment: yes, and i >= 0

We were trying to work out the left hand side of the inequality first

Comment: To me, this is most intuitive if we use calculus. We know that $i = \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n-1$ when $i = 0$, and if we can just show that $\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n-1$ increases faster than $i$ for all $i \geq 0$, then we know that $i \leq \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true as written.

For instance, $2^2 > 1^2$, but $2>1$.

Generally, it is usually a good idea to test out conjectures such as these on many different sets of inputs. If you choose a variety of $x$ and $y$ to try, it's very likely that you will come across a counterexample.